# Is it possible to use FindPrevious when searching with VBA code in a UDF?

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions, udf

I am trying to use VBA for a UDF to manipulate its results based on the "Find" function as it's much quicker than polling every cell looking for results.

I have cut it right back to it's basics to reproduce the error and I still get "Object variable or With block variable not set" error on this part `SearchRange.FindPrevious.Address` (You have to put a stop on the line and step it to get the error, UDF's just quit out without returning the error outside of debug mode)

Here's the kicker, I get the error when trying to use the UDF in a sheet like so: `=testfind("3206-1",E:E)` however when I use it in the immediate window in the VBE like so: `?testfind("3206-1",Range("E:E"))` i get the correct result of `$E$15295` without error.

Code is:

```
Function TestFind(FindString As String, SearchRange As Range)
Dim ActiveAddress As Range
Set ActiveAddress = SearchRange.Find(FindString)
TestFind = SearchRange.FindPrevious.Address
End Function
```

Modified with L42's changes and now it works:

```
Function TestFind(FindString As String, SearchRange As Range)
Dim ActiveAddress As Range
Set ActiveAddress = SearchRange.Find(FindString)
TestFind = SearchRange.Find(FindString, , , , , xlPrevious).Address
End Function
```

Comment: ...are you perhaps needing to put `E:E` in quotes when calling from the original formula? Notice how you Immediate Window query has `"E:E"` but the example you post doesn't.

Comment: @Dan The function is okay. The error comes only when `FindString` not found in the range. So use `Error Handler`. Also call the `Function` from a `Sub`.

Comment: Thanks but no, it's expecting a range and the debug window one is using double quotes as that's how a range is specified in VBA.

Comment: @harun24hr, thanks but why would it not work in the Sheet one but it works in the VBA one? the data has to exist for the VBA use of the function to return.

Comment: Just a final comment, why would you set all those commas instead of just `TestFind = SearchRange.Find(FindString, Searchorder:=xlPrevious).Address` ?

Comment: It could be done that way too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit1:**

This code

```
TestFind = SearchRange.FindPrevious.Address
```

and this as previously suggested:

```
TestFind = SearchRange.FindPrevious(ActiveAddress).Address
```

doesn't work when you use it as worksheet function as what Dan experienced.
Below doesn't directly answer the question but just an alternative.

**Alternative:** Change the `SearchDirection` argument in the `Find` method.

```
Function TestFind2(FindString As String, SearchRange As Range)
    Dim ActiveAddress As Range
    Set ActiveAddress = SearchRange.Find(FindString, , , , , xlPrevious)
    TestFind2 = ActiveAddress.Address
End Function
```

Note: You need to add error handler to trap searches with no match found.

**How to test:**

```
Sub marine()
    Debug.Print TestFind(4, [A:A])
End Sub
```

Comment: Same error. Any syntactical errors would also stop it from working when called in the immediate window.

Comment: @DanDonoghue Really? Just tested and it works at my end.

Comment: It will still return error when 'FindString` is not exist. So, use `On Error Resume Next` to skip error.

Comment: No dramas, it was a scales down beast just to show the error, my final function has error checking in it. Thanks again